# NServiceBus Database Backup

Tags: database, service, backup, nservicebus

I am looking to set up a system that consist of various autonomous services communicating via NServiceBus. This system will be deployed in various configurations (some services may be excluded, services will be setup differently) at client locations. These locations will often be large warehouses and will not have a massive IT infrastructure. The services may all sit on one machine, or on many different ones; this may be different for every site. Most sites will have one active DB server (usually SQL server) and a back-up server. Sites will make scheduled back-ups of the DB at various intervals - let's say daily.

Each service has it's own data store (this could be a truly separate database or segregated tables in a shared schema). Each service of course also has it's own message queues. Although the services are autonomous they do locally store (referentially in their own DB) information from other services as a type of local read-only cache, this data is derived from received messages.

Here is the question: How do I make a meaningful (i.e. consistent and restorable) back-up of this system?

I have read the following related answer by Udi Dahan on this subject: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/12815
My problem with this answer is this: There is no data center, no SAN; no snapshots. There are "normal" sysadmins that are used to backing up DBs on-site and/or off-site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your client sites are not going to invest in some kind of infrastructure to support some sort of fail safe for MSMQ, then you may be able to leverage the Audit/Gateway feature of NSB.  With this turned on you could have the client messages audited and stored over to some infrastructure that you manage.  You would have to work out the details on how to restore the messages, but at least you would have them offsite somewhere.

Comment: Backing up the messages seems easy enough. My primary concern is: How do I keep a the parts of a back-up in sync that is made across various message queues and various databases?

Comment: You will probably have to restore the backup and then replay everything that you have audited since that backup occurred.

Comment: So you continuously back-up the messages and take a DB back-up at an interval; let's once every 24 hours. How do you know which messages still need to replayed in case of a restore? Keeping in mind that a message must be delivered exactly once. The problem is in synchronization and the fact that message may be in some other services' send queue.

Comment: I'm assuming that all the messages are time-stamped and have unique ids.  You may want to take a look at the event store pattern, this functions in a similar way that I'm describing.